# Error undefined method `page'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `page' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007ff3ce5a1da0>
```

How can I fix this? This is my code:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @users = User.where(:username).page params[:page]
  end

end
```

Comment: `page` isn't built into rails.  You get it if you use a pagination gem like `will_paginate` https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate or `kaminari` https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Are you using one of those gems or did you just try a "page" method hoping it would work?

Comment: I just noticed the `where(:username)` ... did you want to say `where(:username => current_user.name)` or something like that?  You're not getting a collection, you're getting a relation.

Comment: I was trying some different things there.  I have now what the documentation has for Kaminari which is: @users = User.count(:username).page params[:page]

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have

```
gem 'kaminari'
```

in your gemfile

And then replace your index code with

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
  # assuming you want to check username not nil
    @users = User.where.not(username: nil).page(params[:page]) 
  end
end
```

You would only need the where query if you wanted to limit the Users by a username as SteveTurczyn stated in the comments. Additionally the first assignment to @users is overridden in the next step. This could be changed to

```
@users = User.all
@users = @users.page(params[:page])
```

if you wanted to keep the two line syntax

Comment: Thanks for the help ob264 and Steve.  I finally got it to work!!

Comment: You're welcome. If that solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer?